# How to access constant value from spec file?

Tags: ruby

I get a `uninitialized constant` error, when I run this rspec by `rspec foo_spec.rb`.

```
# foo.rb
class Foo
  FILENAME = "filename.txt"
  def filename
    FILENAME
  end
end

# foo_spec.rb
require_relative 'foo'

describe Foo do
  describe "#filename" do
    it "should have right filename" do
      foo = Foo.new
      expect(foo.filename).to eq FILENAME
    end
  end
end
```

I confirmed if I change `FILENAME` to `"filename.txt"`, the test passes.

How should I use constant value with rspec?

Comment: Your description is self contradictory. By definition, a constant is not a variable. There can't be such thing as a constant variable.

Comment: That was my English mistake. I meant "constant value".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't an rspec problem, it's a Ruby problem. You need to qualify the constant with the class in which its declared. `FILENAME` should be `Foo::FILENAME`.

You can only refer to it by `FILENAME` within the context of `Foo`. Otherwise, supposing I had a class `Bar` which also defined a constant called `FILENAME`, how could Ruby figure out which one I was referring to?

Comment: I thought `describe Foo` suffice to tell Ruby where the constant is defined. Anyway, you solved my problem, Thanks!